# Where is Allah located?

Tags: allah, hadith-interpretation, belief, aqidah

It is said that Allah sits on the throne which is above the 7 heavens in the A'rsh.

It is also mentioned in a Hadith that when the servants go to sleep at night, Allah descends to the first sky and says 'anyone of you wants forgiveness tonight'?

My question is:
While half of the world is in daylight and the other half will be in darkness every day, this implies that Allah should be located in the first sky forever.

Please provide a logical answer to this fallacy.

Comment: Not really a fallacy when you apply logic from 3-D dimensional world to one of n-dimensions (or possibly something different all together) coupled with your assumption that Allah physically descends to the first sky. Nonetheless, it would be interesting to hear a few replies to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Allah in the lowest heaven all the time?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/is-allah-in-the-lowest-heaven-all-the-time)

Comment: @Envayo gives a perfect answer to the question imo.

Comment: see also https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/where-did-the-concept-of-allah-being-everywhere-come-from?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering the question I'd like to clear some misconceptions regarding the belief of the Muslims.

First of all, **NOWHERE** in the Islamic literature it is said that Allah subhanahu wa-ta'ala ***SITS***. Sitting is an act of creation and so far I've gone through Islamic literatures, I've found no instances where it is said that Allah ta'ala *SITS* (نعوذ بلله من ذالك). To attribute anything towards Allah which Allah ta'ala has not attributed towards *Him*, in terms of Islamic jurisdiction, is regarded as a fabrication inside *Deen*. So, from a Muslims point of view, they do not possess any such belief.

Second of all,
as you have said in your question, **"Where is Allah Located? [Logical Question]"**

If you try to answer to a question, I think it would be easier for you to understand. Can anyone answer me, **"Where was Allah before the entire creation?"** `I hope my question is understood.`

Were there any place to call ***"where"*** before the entire creation? Time, Space etc. are relative dimensions. Muslims believe that all of these `time, matter, space and all other dimensions` are creations of Allah. So, you cannot really say where is Allah located. Because Allah subhanahu wa ta'ala is exalted and free from dimensions and bindings.

---

There are several Hadith regarding this issue ([example](https://sunnah.com/urn/1287140)).

---

The answer to your question would be

- If you **directly** ask what does these hadith mean then all the Muslims will answer you that Allah knows the best. The salaf i.e. the great Imams and the Fuqaha of the golden era used to read these and say we bring Iman in these ayah and hadith. We do not ask why and how.
- But if you take a **metaphoric** meaning as many great later Imams have done, the answer is very simple. **Here it is referring to the forgiveness, blessings which descends from the heavens from Allah for each part of the globe.**

By taking this meaning you can come out of that fallacy that whether Allah is located in the nearest sky or not.

`To remind again... to attribute any dimension for Allah is prohibited in Islamic jurisprudence.`

Answer (score -1):

Allah descends in a way that befits his majesty. You can't descend every night if your already bound to be in the first heaven.

Allah comes down specifically in the **last-third** of the night which was mentioned in the latter part of the Hadith, so not the full night. (You can work out the time zones :), too busy right now
)

Allah isn't constrained to any laws of the universe since Allah is the creator.
Time and any dimensional limitations fall under the laws of universe.

Anyway this is beyond our mental capacity, we cannot assume the unseen.
If everything in this universe is imperfect to a degree, then there must be a perfect being.

All praise and glory is to Allah.

> **May Allah Forgive me for any mistakes, and Allah knows best.**

Answer (score -2):

With the Name of Allah most Gracious, most Compassionate
First of all we can not consider (compare) Allah like any one in this word
No one in this word is like Allah
All Says in about 8 times
“KUN FAYAKUN” (“‘Be,’ and it is”) means Allah do not need to go some if Allah want to do some thing, he will just say "Kun" and it will be happened
the question is "how will it be happened or who will do it ?"
the answer is "it is the beyond the limitation of the human mind" because laws of the universe obey Allah not Allah obey the Laws of the universe
similarly if Allah want to go somewhere he do not need to go physically and i will repeat my word again "it is the beyond the limitation of the human mind to understand that how Allah will go somewhere"
if you want to understand it scientifically and with logics
then read Albert Einstein theory of theory of relativity
he says that
no one can attain speed of light
if he do so there will be there will be three changing at all in its behaviour

- he will have infinite mass (means a mass which can not be measurable)
- the length will be contract for him (means a wast distance will be tiny for him)
- time dilation will be occurred for him (time will not end for him or moving clocks run slow for him)
  Allah says in Quran (Surah Noor ayah 35)
  اللَّهُ نُورُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ (Allah is the Light of the heavens and the earth)
  in this Ayah Allah describing one of his characteristics that he is light
  this is the scientific proof that no one can be compared with Allah and Allah has no limits
  but as far as science is concerned science can be changed or altered with strong reasoning but islam can not because it is the religion made by Allah for us
  may Allah forgive me if i can not explain it well or explained something wrong
  All praise and glory is to Allah.